# PayPal verify fail with Invalid

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up PayPal Ipn and it is failing on some orders verification. I found that it fails if users name has some non standard letters like `&last_name=Montalvo Agüera`
Do I need to change encoding?

```
var request = "cmd=_notify-validate&.......";

const string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);
            //Set values for the request back
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            req.ContentLength = request.Length;

            var streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            streamOut.Write(request);
            streamOut.Close();
            var streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            var strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            streamIn.Close();

            Response.Write(strResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to url-encode the parameters. That's what the line `req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` means. It's you making a promise to the HTTP server (in this case, PayPal's www.paypal.com). The promise is that any data you send will be url-encoded. This means you have to escape any special characters. This includes characters like `?` and `&` and `%` and also characters like `ü`.

To url-encode the name, you need to build the request with the url-encoded name:

```
string request = "cmd=_notify-validate&......."; // don't include "last_name="
string name = "Montalvo Agüera";
request += "last_name=" + Server.UrlEncode(name);
```

Comment: Still Invalid. Two days trying to get the problem solved without any success. I get IPN Messages from "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) details" page, some of them works some fails. I even think just remove Validation.

Comment: Could you edit the question so it has two example requests - one that works and one that doesn't? There's probably something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //for proxy
        //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
        //req.Proxy = proxy;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

If it still doesn't work try to change the encoding to UTF8

Comment: I get the same problem. Invalid status on some orders.

Comment: If I change it to UTF8 I get error "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."

Comment: I think you should contact paypal